# Border and background inside of padding margin, with Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have repeating rows/columns setup with Bootstrap's grid system. I want to create padding between these elements, but have their border and background reside inside of that padding. I have tried using margin but that jacks with Bootstrap's grid layout on the column level.

The below is a very trimmed down version of what I'm working with, which illustrates the point. I would like to modify this so that the blue border hugs the white inner box, and you don't see any red (in my case it would show up behind text). I need to achieve this without modifying the essential html layout of what's there already, so relying just on CSS.

To clarify what I'm going after... I want to add padding between the rows & columns. If I just straight add padding to the outer div (as exists below) the border and background color extend outside of that padding. I want the border and the background color to exist within the boundaries of the padding I add.

I have tried using a variety of box-sizing settings to no avail, as well as all manner of padding/margin I could think of.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2v94yg2s/

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="grid-data row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-data {
  padding: 15px;
}

.grid-data  > div {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-data  > div > div {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wait, so you want the blue border to cover the red part? What's the point of having the red background then? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @user1301428 I added a clarification paragraph

Comment: Have you tried using `box-sizing: border-box;`? That would make the border appear **inside** the div rather than outside them (the default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up wrapping the repeat's contents inside another div, and only keeping the padding on the outer.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically want is change the grid's "gutter".

If you want this to change globally in your website, the easy solution is to change the @grid-gutter-width variable in Bootstrap's "variables.less" file and rebuild your CSS.

If you want this for one specific feature, I'd recommend not using your grid for this. Generating an alternate grid with increased gutter is probably a bit of overkill, so you could roll your own CSS. Flexbox can be very useful and successful if you're not trying to mix it in the Bootstrap grid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Webberig, due to a whole slew of nonsense (I am working a huge app that another developer built, tackling just a few pages and dealing with a bunch of stuff all over the place), I cannot do that. There must be a way to dictate the border and background to go inside of the padding without resorting to such drastic measures, and without having to modify the html structure.

Comment: Just add an extra class to the containing element and you can override all default grid styles. No need to restructure but it's a maintenance nightmare. 

Writing your own CSS for a multiple-column component is hardly drastic...